# zsh: zparseopts not behaving as expected

Tags: zsh

It seems that I must be using `zparseopts` incorrectly, because I'm not getting what the expected output is for this simple example scripts.

`zparseopts` seems to erroneously assume that `-h` and `--help` take an argument, even though they are declared without the `:`.

```sh
set -- --help --checkout foo 1 2 3 4

declare -A misc

zparseopts -E -D -K \
        -A misc \
        '-checkout:' \
        h \
        -help

for k v in ${(@kv)misc}; do
    echo flag $k: $v
done

echo "argv $@"
```

This should print out

```
flag --help:
flag --checkout: foo
argv 1 2 3 4
```

But instead prints as if --help took an argument.  Am I using the `-A` and associative array incorrectly?

```
flag --help: --checkout
flag foo:
argv: 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that `zparseopts` is doing exactly what you want. The issue is that
the later `echo` statements are not displaying the keys and values in the associative array correctly.

Unusually for `zsh`, you need more quotes. Try replacing the `for` loop with this:

```
printf 'flag %s: %s\n' "${(kv@)misc}"
```

The real fix is the double quotes paired with the `@` parameter expansion flag; this ensures that empty values will be treated as separate words in the result. The printf is just a shorter way to loop through the key-value pairs.

You can also display the value of an associative array (or almost any variable) with `typeset`:

```
typeset '@' 'misc'
```

Comment: Confirmed!  Not sure why I didn't notice that, I usually aggressively quote everything!